# More plots in an unique page: the titles are hidden

Tags: r, plot, title, par, r-corrplot

I'm trying to plot 6x4 graphs on a page, each with its title. I have used a lot of options.

```
 pdf("myDocument.pdf") #, width = 50, height =60)

      par(mfrow=c(6,4), oma = c(2,0,2,0) + 0.0)
      par(mar=c(2, 0, 1, 0) + 0.1)
      par(cex.axis=0.1)
      par( mgp = c(1, 1, 0),
           omd = c(1.0, 0, 1.0, 0),
           pin=c(10,10),
           plt = c(1,1,1,1),
           usr =c(1,0,1,0)
      )
      for(z in 1:ncol(df_finale)){
        ...    
        corrplot(matriceTermine, 
                 title = colnames(df_finale)[z],
                 xaxs = "i",
                #insig = "pch",
                 #pch.col="blue",
                 #addrect=24, rect.lwd=10,
                 #addCoefasPercent=T,
                 method = "shade", # shade   ellipse
                 order="original", 
                 col=col1(11),
                 addgrid.col="grey",
                 addCoef.col="grey",
                 mar = c(0,0,0,0),
                 cl.cex= 0.2, cl.pos = "n",  # 0.2
                 tl.pos = "n", tl.cex= 0.3, tl.offset = 0.9, tl.srt = 90, 
                 #tl.pos="d")
      }
    dev.off()
```

It results:
[image]

Which parameters do I have to modify to make the titles visible?
And suppose I want to reduce the dimensions of the plots (to give extra-spaces to the titles), how can I do?

Comment: Can you try `cex.main=2` ?

Comment: It just makes my titles "bold", but they are still hidden. I think a way could be to make the image smaller, but how can I do that?

Comment: Try to adjust the `mar` parameter in the loop

Comment: I have tried that too. At the end I have solved with "line".

Answer (score 0):

I have solved in this way, adding:

```
...
corrplot(matriceTermine, 
         #title = colnames(df_finale)[z],
         ...,
         method = "s")
title(colnames(df_finale[z]), line = -0.1, cex = 2.5, font=3, cex.main = 2)
...
```

With

> `line = - q`

it's possible to "move" the title of q.

For successive modifications I suggest to save the plot in a "*svg*" and modifying it with *Inkscape*.

Comment: Note that for reproducibility and automation reasons, modifying a plot outside R is often a bad practice

Comment: You're perfectly right, but sometimes one needs a "quick result". Achieved that, one has always to fix the issues directly in R.